Type error: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'NextPage'
"use client"
import React from 'react';
import Sidebar from './page';
import type { NextPage } from 'next';

interface LayoutProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps): NextPage<LayoutProps> {

  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <Sidebar />
      <main className="main-content">{children}</main>
    </div>
  );
}

`this is my code for layout.tsx in nextjs(14.2) project when i build error will show.
can you fix the error`

In React, a layout component is expected to return JSX (JavaScript XML), so you have to change your return type to
export default function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps) {

or
export default function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps): JSX.Element {

